# SQLiteAssetHelper generates error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-assets

I am using SqliteAssetHelper to import a database from the asset folder and copy it to the standard database application folder.

It works quite randomly though...when I replace the .zip file in my asset folder with a new one and I run the application I get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime(20036): Caused by: com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/adinspect.zip file in assets or target folder not writable
```

but I am sure the file "adinpect.zip" is there. I just updated my database schema, re-zipped it and replaced the file in the asset folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: is the table "android_metadata" in my db causing this error?

Comment: Are you sure a database file is in there? And not sql or something. Maybe try refreshing your assets folder after you replace. Also the zip name will be used as the database name and not the one inside it. The android_metadata might be an issue. Not cause it's there but if the statement inside it is wrong. I'm just trying to put all the possibilities out there. I use it all the time and have no issue

Comment: Refresh was the key. @mango, If you add that as an answer I will accept it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you refresh the assets folder after you replace a file. Sometimes eclipse doesn't register the file change.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but I also had miss named the assets/databases directory (I had assets/database).

Just thought I would add this in case someone else runs into the problem.